# How can I use variables (or formatting commands) in a header row of a \pgfplotstable table?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

My first reaction to reading the [pgfplotstable manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) was:

*Why would anybody in their right mind use the tabular environment for generating tables?*

### Advantages of pgfplotstable

- No need to specify number of columns
- Global formatting settings
- Local formatting settings that can override global settings when necessary (etc. `longtable` needed, changes in cell alignment, etc.)

In my experiments with pgfplotstable, I've run into some bumps:

- [merging multiple columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236215/how-can-i-use-multicolumn-in-a-pgfplotstable-table)
- adding formatting commands to text within header rows

## Problem

- `columns/<name>/.style` is the issue. Formatting commands and new commands cannot be used as column identifiers (called "names" in `pgfplotstable`). I need to find a way to keep the text names in the header row (for pdf output), but tell `pgfplotstable` to use column indexes (e.g. 0,1,2,etc.) for uniquely identifying the columns.
- I use a `\texttt{}` in my command and the file fails to typeset.
- I also use `\texttt{}` inside of a `\newcommand` to demonstrate both cases.

### Example of Issue

Given:

```
\newcommand\test{\texttt{hello}.bye}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{%
col1 & \test{} & col3\\
here & more & stuff\\
}%
```

Results in:

```
columns/col1/.style={}
columns/\texttt{hello}.bye/.style={} % Not a valid column name!
columns/col3/.style={}
```

Obviously the second column (index 1) does not work as Percusse mentioned in a comment.

This leaves me with the conlusion that the solution might involve automatically stripping the formatting from column names OR forcing `pgfplotstable` to use indexes (0,1,2, etc.) in place of names. In either case, the columns must become valid keys for `pgfplotstable` to reference:**

```
columns/col1/.style={}
columns/hello.bye/.style={}
columns/col3/.style={}
```

OR

```
columns/0/.style={}
columns/1/.style={}
columns/2/.style={}
```

---

## Example that works

Desired result: replace a cell with \test{}.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{% Global config
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    col sep=&,
    row sep=\\,
    column type=l,
    column type={>{\fontseries{bx}\selectfont\color{orange}}l}, %see sec 2.6 for defining column types
    string type,
    postproc cell content/.append style={ % see sec 3.2
    /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\fontseries{\seriesdefault}\selectfont\color{black}}{}}
}%
\newcommand\test{\texttt{test}.bye}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{%
col1 & col2 & col3\\ % <-- I want to replace a cell with \test{} in a header row
here & more & stuff\\
for & good & looks\\
}%
\end{document}
```

## Example that does *not* work

Desired result: replace a cell with \test{}.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{% Global config
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    col sep=&,
    row sep=\\,
    column type=l,
    column type={>{\fontseries{bx}\selectfont\color{orange}}l}, %see sec 2.6 for defining column types
    string type,
    postproc cell content/.append style={ % see sec 3.2
    /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\fontseries{\seriesdefault}\selectfont\color{black}}{}}
}%
\newcommand\test{\texttt{test}.bye}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{%
col1 & \test{} & col3\\ % <-- I want to replace a cell with \test{} in a header row
here & more & stuff\\
for & good & looks\\
}%
\end{document}
```

---

## Huge thanks to Symbol 1 and Guuk for making this possible:

The ability to:

- globally format specific rows (see [Pgfplotstable one row in bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130835/13552))
- override global formatting with standard latex formatting (important detail: also in header rows by cheating—see Symbol 1's answer)
- include commands within header rows (again cheating—see Symbol's answer)

[image]

## Demonstration

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgflibrary{decorations.fractals}

\pgfplotstableset{
    string type,col sep=&,row sep=\\,
    header=false,
    every head row/.style={output empty row},
    every row no 0/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    highlightrow/.style={
        postproc cell content/.append code={
           \count0=\pgfplotstablerow
            \advance\count0 by1
            \ifnum\count0=#1
            \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add={\bfseries\color{red}}{}}
            \fi
        },
    },
    highlightrow={1}
}%

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset{
    \LaTeX & \textit{italic} & \textcolor{orange}{orange} & \reflectbox{reflect} & $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ & \tikz\draw[decoration=Koch snowflake]decorate{decorate{decorate{decorate{(0,0)--(1,0)}}}}; \\
    Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit & amet & consectetur \\
    adipisicing & elit & sed & do & eiusmod & tempor \\
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\fullexpandargs` is a macro from `xstring` why do you have it here?

Comment: @percusse I removed it. It was a mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Show me a solution

This is **"a" solution** that uses `row no 0` as the header. (usually the header is `row no -1`). So PgfplotsTable will no longer put the entries inside `\csname`. Notice that you need to reset the style for `row no 0` if you assign some style for some columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgflibrary{decorations.fractals}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    string type,col sep=&,row sep=\\,
    header=false,
    every head row/.style={output empty row},
    every row no 0/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{
    \LaTeX & \textit{italic} & \textcolor{orange}{orange} & \reflectbox{reflect} & $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ & \tikz\draw[decoration=Koch snowflake]decorate{decorate{decorate{decorate{(0,0)--(1,0)}}}}; \\
    Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit & amet & consectetur \\
    adipisicing & elit & sed & do & eiusmod & tempor \\
}

\end{document}
```

### Combining with cell-processing (update)

There are ≥3 stages of cell-processing. Perhaps `typeset cell` is the latest one. (It is even too late to be a processing because there is nothing to do with the literal content then.) Anyway, these keys will probably work as usual.

[image: œ]

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    string type,col sep=&,row sep=\\,
    header=false,
    every head row/.style={output empty row},
    every row no 0/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    /pgfplots/table/typeset cell/.code={
        \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\bfseries\color{orange}#1\\}
            \else
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\bfseries\color{orange}#1&}
            \fi
        \else
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1\\}
            \else
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1&}
            \fi
        \fi
    },
]{
    \LaTeX & \textit{italic} & \textcolor{red}{R}\textcolor{green}{G}\textcolor{blue}{B} & \reflectbox{reflect} & $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ & \tikz\draw[decoration=Koch snowflake]decorate{decorate{decorate{decorate{(0,0)--(1,0)}}}}; \\
    Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit & amet & consectetur \\
    adipisicing & elit & sed & do & eiusmod & tempor \\
}
```

### Show me the official Solution

Same output as before

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    string type,col sep=&,row sep=\\,
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    columns/LaTeX/.style         ={column name=\LaTeX},
    columns/italic/.style        ={column name=\textit{italic}},
    columns/orange/.style        ={column name=\textcolor{orange}{orange}},
    columns/reflect/.style       ={column name=\reflectbox{reflect}},
    columns/eipi+1/.style        ={column name={$e^{i\pi}+1=0$}},
    columns/Koch snowflake/.style={column name={\tikz\draw[decoration=Koch snowflake]decorate{decorate{decorate{decorate{(0,0)--(1,0)}}}};}},
]{
    LaTeX & itslic & orange & reflect & eipi+1 & Koch snowflake \\
    Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit & amet & consectetur \\
    adipisicing & elit & sed & do & eiusmod & tempor \\
}
```

### Show me the reason

Turns out that this is a basic TeX phenomenon which is totally reasonable but no one will ever, logically, think about it. In the following example, I tried to pack `\ttfamily` into the name of a control sequence.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
    \expandafter\let\csname\ttfamily test\endcsname\relax
\end{document}
```

Then

- `\ttfamily` is expanded;
- a `\protect` is unveiled;
- TeX read `\protect` before `\endcsname` and complained.

> ```
> ./236210 copy.tex:7: Missing \endcsname inserted.
> <to be read again> 
>                    \protect 
> l.7   \expandafter\let\csname\ttfamily
>                                       test\endcsname\relax
> ?
> ```

(`\protect` is `\relax`, it cannot be part of csname. Otherwise it is logically contradictive, right?)

---

Back to `pgfplotstable`. This package did plenty of magics and inevitably it put the  entry inside a csname. Then BOOM: Since `\test` led to `\texttt` to `\ttfamily` and to `\protect`, TeX complained!

---

So the next question may be whether I can replace `\newcommand` by `\edef`? For instance

```
\xdef\test{{\ttfamily test}}
```

The answer is still **NO** but for different reason. In fact, due to the design of font-switches, there is internally something like

> ```
> \xdef \font@name {\curr@fontshape}
> ```

But since there is another `\edef` outside, the following line is executed

> ```
> \xdef \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 {\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 }
> ```

So Once you apply `\test`... BOOM.

---

The following *paraphrase* even gives another error.

```
\xdef\test{\textit{test}}
```

---

Conclusion: Never rely on any specific package for, especially, tables.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! Such a refreshing answer…until the end haha. Despite your report, I am going to keep my hope alive for a solution. `pgfplotstable` has too much potential for my purposes :)

Comment: Awesome. So it *is* possible. Is it also possible to post-process cell content starting after row 0? My intention: I'd like to format row 0 (the new header row) bold and orange. Everything else should be black and not formatted by the pgf settings. You mentioned "reseting" row 0…

Comment: @macmadness86 It is, as usual, possible to **post-process cell content starting *at* row 0**. So you need to exclude row 0 by hand if you want to **post-process cell content starting *after* row 0**. But if you want **Everything else black and not formatted** then it is called **formatting only row 0**, which is demonstrated in the second section above.

Comment: Thanks for your latest update! It is helpful to see different ways of doing things. I found another way to highlight specific rows. Please don't delete anything! I think this is a great reference.

Answer (score 7):

I think you have too high expectations from `pgfplotstable`. While it is certainly true that it does many amazing things, it is still just a wrapper around the typical TeX tabular and table mechanisms. So in the end what you end up with is an auto generated tabular code. And you have to use the package towards that mindset.

Here for example, you are changing the colors of everything twice since it is the way to go in the usual colortbl and so on package practice. The idea of this package is automation of certain properties of the table, not offering an alternative syntax hence you have to really pay attention to which property is set when and where. You can intercept values of the table at one place but you have to change the formatting at somewhere else. And that takes some time to get used to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotstableset{
  paint row/.style={
    /pgfplots/table/typeset cell/.code={%
      \ifnum\c@pgfplotstable@colindex=\c@pgfplotstable@numcols\relax%
      \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\textcolor{#1}{##1}\\}%
      \else\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\textcolor{#1}{##1}&}%
      \fi%
    },
  }
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\test{\texttt{test}}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  string type,
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule,paint row=orange},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  every row 1 column 1/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\Large\test}},
]{
col1 col2 col3
here more stuff
for good looks
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "So in the end what you end up with is an auto-generated tabular code." <-- The gravity of that statement is incredible. That is *exactly* why `pgfplotstable` is so great! I'm dealing with a multiple of documents (edited by many people at any time via subversion) that require the same look. Maybe my expectation are too high, but you can probably see why I am so excited! Thanks for your insights too.

Comment: I tried typesetting your code and I ended up with: `Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.12' unknown in choice key '/pgfplots/compat/anchors' I am going to ignore this key.`

Comment: @macmadness Update your pgfplots package or use `compat=newest`. But update it anyways.

Comment: Ok. After updating it worked, however, your answer still fails to meet my requirement of writing `\texttt{}`or some other macro in a cell. I mean, I know you got one cell to appear as if a macro were there, but that solution is unscalable (therefore defeating the purpose of `pgfplotstable`). I am dealing with hundreds of tables and I am trying to bring some order into their formatting.

Comment: @macmadness86 Huh? It is `\texttt` in the snapshot. What do you mean?

Comment: @macmadness86 Change `\Large\test` to `\Large\ttfamily##1`. Is that what you mean? If it is that is a really convoluted way of asking it :)

Comment: Ah! I see the source of confusion. No, that is not what I meant. You interpreted my line `% <-- I want to replace a cell with \test{}`as wanting to create a function that replaces that cell's contents in a preprocess, correct?. I meant simple typing for example `\\test{}` or `\texttt` instead of good—directly in the tabular code. I will update my question immediately.

Comment: @macmadness86 OK that I understand now. The first row is a special row for pgfplotstable. It also names that column with whatever is given in the table. So it is trying to name the column with a typesetting command which obviously won't work.  So a simple substitution works anywhere else (try it together with removing the `every row 1 col 1` stuff). But for the header row you need to add more precautions. That's why you are having trouble.  I would not do that anyways. Because this package is towards readily made data --> tabular automation. Not to replicate tabular.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I see the trouble. The deal is that we have certain macros like product release names or whatever that are set by a server process (and sometimes those names include formatting commands for colors or italics etc. e.g. `product name.\texttt{product line}`). These variables *might* appear in a table header. In that case I could maybe find a way to define the column names in the parameters and substitute them for text names like you said.