# citations in pgfplotstable

Tags: bibtex, pgfplotstable

So I'm calling data in to a `pgfplotstable` with

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma]{example.txt}
```

which has been working fine, until I tried to include a citation in my example.txt file with `\cite{somebozo}`. The error message from the compiler is that there is an `extra }` Somewhere just after the `pgfplotstabletypeset` command.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `pgfplotstable` assumes numbers, and will try to parse the content of the cells as numbers. If you set `string type` for the column containing the citation it seems to work fine:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents*}{example.txt}
x,y,meta
1,2,\cite{aksin}
2,3,\cite{angenendt}
3,7,\cite{doody}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document} 
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
   col sep=comma,
   display columns/2/.style={string type} % column count starts at 0, col 2 is third column
]{example.txt}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Citation in header

I don't have a good solution for this case at the moment, though I do have a workaround. Remove the citation from the `.csv` file, and replace the column name for the column in question with something containing a citation.

Alternatively, if you don't need any parsing of the values in the columns, you can use the method described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236364/586

There may well be better ways of doing this, but I'm not that well versed in `pgfplotstable` trickery.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents*}{example.txt}
x,y,whatever % note no citation here
1,2,\cite{aksin}
2,3,\cite{angenendt}
3,7,\cite{doody}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{example2.txt}
x,y,meta\cite{glashow}
1,2,\cite{aksin}
2,3,\cite{angenendt}
3,7,\cite{doody}
\end{filecontents*}    
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document} 
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
   col sep=comma,
   display columns/2/.style={string type},
   every col no 2/.style={column name={meta\cite{glashow}}} % redefine column name
]{example.txt}


\pgfplotstabletypeset[
   col sep=comma,
   header=false,
   every head row/.style={output empty row},
   string type
]{example2.txt}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your Method, it seems to work well, except that in my case the citations are in the header row, and this seems to not work on the header row. Do you know how I can put the citation in the header row and have it read correctly?

Comment: @seanread Will have a look. (This highlights the value of a good [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) by the way, with one of those I wouldn't have made any wrong assumptions.)

Comment: sorry about that, will remember for next time

Comment: @seanread I don't know of any brilliant solutions, but I added a workaround.