# pgfplotstable: highlight entire rows and columns

Tags: pgfplotstable, pgfmath

This is a follow-up on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286384/making-row-bold-and-keeping-other-formatting-in-pgfplotstable). With `pgfplotstable`, I would like to create a style to highlight an entire row and/or column. Zarko's answer at the linked question shows how to **bolden** an entire row. It seemed pretty straightforward to extend that approach to an entire column... except that if I bolden rows and columns, the intersecting cells are "un-bolden". Help.

MWE:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

    \begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
       A,    B,  C
    0.10, 1000,  1
    0.20, 2000,  2
    0.30, 3000,  3
    \end{filecontents*}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.dat}\mytable

    % Highlight entire row
    \pgfplotstableset{% 
        highlightrow/.style={
            postproc cell content/.append code={
               \count0=\pgfplotstablerow
                \advance\count0 by1
                \ifnum\count0=#1
                \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add={$\bf}{$}}%
                \fi
            },
        },
    }

    % Highlight entire column
    \pgfplotstableset{% 
        highlightcol/.style={
            postproc cell content/.append code={
               \count0=\pgfplotstablecol
                \advance\count0 by1
                \ifnum\count0=#1
                \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add={$\bf}{$}}%
                \fi
            },
        },
    }

    \begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        columns/1/.style = {string type, column type = {l}},
        highlightrow = {2},
        highlightcol = {2},
        ]\mytable
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Zarko, you may be interested in this. Your template was excellent, thanks. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286384/

Comment: meanwhile you receive good answer :-). btw, your link in question is broken.

Comment: Thanks Zarko! I have fixed the link. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this? (**EDIT**: fixed spaces, big thanks to @PatrickT!)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
   A,    B,  C
0.10, 1000,  1
0.20, 2000,  2
0.30, 3000,  3
\end{filecontents*}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.dat}\mytable

% Highlight entire row
\pgfplotstableset{% 
    highlightrow/.style={
        postproc cell content/.append code={
           \count0=\pgfplotstablerow%
            \advance\count0 by1%
            \ifnum\count0=#1%
            \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add={\ifmmode\else\boldmath\fi$}{$}}%
            \fi%
        },
    },
}

% Highlight entire column
\pgfplotstableset{% 
    highlightcol/.style={
        postproc cell content/.append code={
           \count0=\pgfplotstablecol
            \advance\count0 by1
            \ifnum\count0=#1
            \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add={\ifmmode\else\boldmath\fi$}{$}}
            \fi
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/1/.style = {string type, column type = {l}},
    highlightrow = {2},
    highlightcol = {2},
    ]\mytable
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ``\boldmath``! brilliant, thanks marmot!

Comment: Or maybe it was ``\ifmmode``! P.S. I added ``\bf`` after ``\boldmath`` to make it work in my use case. My MWE was a little too easy I guess.

Comment: @PatrickT It is sort of both, I think. The issue is that one should not use `\bf`, but rather `\bfseries` or `\boldmath`. And because of nesting you had "double math mode" at the intersection of the special row  with the special column. It seems like pgfplotstable takes care of this but not of the the `\bf` statement in the desired way.

Comment: changed it to ``\boldmath\bfseries`` and it works too. Thanks again!

Comment: I noticed the code was adding a lot of extra space (especially if used repeatedly). To fix this, I added a percentage sign at the end of each of the lines that start with ``\pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add=``

Comment: @PatrickT Good catch!