# How to procedually set column type in pgfplotstable for each column individually?

Tags: tables, macros, pgfplotstable, foreach, for-loop

For a project I am working on, I would like to write a wrapper macro `\fancyTable`, which communicates with `pgfplotstable` in the background. The user should be able to specify the column alignment as a comma separated list and the path to the file containing the table data. Additional complication is that the data is in general an arbitrary string; it can be a time stamp, parts of a sentence or a number.  In the current testing phase, the wrapper macro looks like this:

`\fancyTable[r,c,c,l]{FILEPATH}`

The current design requirement is that it has to work for an arbitrary number of columns (so hard-coding for specific cases is not an option). However, all my attempts for procedural assignment of the `column style` did not work (or even worse lead to different glitches for each compilation).

Since I tried a lot of possibilities already, I decided to give a complete overview. My remaining open questions are at the very end
under the section **Questions**. So feel free to scroll to the end.

### Starting point

Currently, I managed to hard-code a table.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} % standalone or minimal do not work well with longtable

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{filecontents}{pgfplotstable_proc-column-style_example.csv}
        date, time, time zone, event
        2019/01/01, 00:00, CET, server installation finished
        2019/01/01, 00:05, CET, server successfully booted
        2019/01/01, 00:06, CET, starting xyz daemon
        2019/01/01, 00:10, CET, admin login
        2019/12/31, 23:58, CET, sudo reboot
        2019/12/31, 23:59, CET, server reboot
    \end{filecontents}

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        begin table=\begin{longtable},%
        end table=\end{longtable},%
        header=false,% no specific header data
        col sep=comma,%
        every head row/.style={% 
            output empty row,% prevent printing of column numbers
        },%
        every odd row/.style={before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},% highlighting of every second data row
        every first row/.append style={after row={\midrule}},% horizontal line after header
        string type,% necessary for correct processing of table content
        columns/0/.style={column type=r},%
        columns/3/.style={column type=l},%
        % modified from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130835/pgfplotstable-one-row-in-bold
        postproc cell content/.append code={% setting first row bold
            \count0=\pgfplotstablerow %
            \advance\count0 by1 %
            \ifnum\count0=1 %
            \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=\textbf{#1}}%
            \fi %
        },
    ]{pgfplotstable_proc-column-style_example.csv}
\end{document}
```

The compilation returns the following table:
[image]

However, the column alignment is fixed:

```
columns/0/.style={column type=r},%
columns/3/.style={column type=l},%
```

which leads to issues if the input data is changed.

### Attempt 1: `pgfplotstable` macros

My first idea was to use macros already provided by `pgfplotstable`, but I only manage to print column related content with `\pgfplotstableforeachcolumn`. Next, I tried to create a for-loop with `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`, which also failed. As far as my limited understanding of `pgf` and `pgfplotstable`, it either did not work since I did not manage to access the table data properly or that the macro was not designed to do what I tried to ask of it.

### Attempt 2: `\foreach` with `\protected@xappto`

Another idea I had was to create a string containing the alignment information in a helper macro `\columnAlign` and insert the content of the macro in `\pgfplotstabletypeset[\columnAlign]{FILENAME}`. For prototyping, I used the hacky approach of combining `\foreach`with `\protected@xappto`, with which I had some success in the past for creating table content on-the-fly. Of course, this did not work; so the `MWE` will not compile...

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{filecontents}{pgfplotstable_proc-column-style_example.csv}
        date,time,time zone, event
        2019/01/01, 00:00, CET, server installation finished
        2019/01/01, 00:05, CET, server successfully booted
        2019/01/01, 00:06, CET, starting xyz daemon
        2019/01/01, 00:10, CET, admin login
        2019/12/31, 23:58, CET, sudo reboot
        2019/12/31, 23:59, CET, server reboot
    \end{filecontents}
    
    \pgfplotstableread[header=false,col sep=comma]{pgfplotstable_proc-column-style_example.csv}\loadedtable

    \def\columnAlign{}% define empty helper macro
    \makeatletter
    \foreach \col in {0,1} {% iterate over all columns in \loadedtable
        \protected@xappto\columnAlign{% append column style definition
            columns/\col/.style=\{column type=l\}, 
        }%
    }%
    \makeatother

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        every head row/.style={% 
            output empty row,%
        },%
        string type,%
        \columnAlign
    ]\loadedtable
\end{document}
```

There were many issues with escaping characters like `, = { }`, which I could not fix. I tried `\csname ... \endcsname`, `\expandafter`, etc.

### Attempt 3: `\input{}` (do not try!)

From the start, I was certain that this will break `pgfplotstable`; but if you do not try it, you do not know it for sure...

The idea was that I could probably load an externally generated tex-file which `pgfplotstable` would be able to load without the `\csname` and the expansion issues. Or alternatively, this might be a way to generate a pipe via `\input{|"PIPE CONTENT"}`.

Like expected, calling `\pgfplotstable[\input{FILE1}]{FILE2}` was not compiling properly. The compilation froze/looped and not even an error message was produced.

### Attempt 4: custom column styles and `./list`

Attempt 4 is a very similar to attempt 2. However, it tried to utilize the `pgfplotstable`-feature that you can define custom column styles in the output table domain, over which can be iterated.

```
\pgfplotstableset{%
    left column/.style={%
        /pgfplots/table/display columns/#1/.style={column type=l}%
    },%
    center column/.style={%
        /pgfplots/table/display columns/#1/.style={column type=c}%
    },%
    right column/.style={%
        /pgfplots/table/display columns/#1/.style={column type=r}%
    },%
}%
```

If the styles gets called, e. g. `left column/.list={LIST}`, the style will be applied to all column indices provided in `LIST`.

The styles do also accept macros as an input. This would have been a possibility to generate several "macro arrays" with `\protected@xappto`, containing the indices of the columns to which the style should be applied. If no column should get a certain style applied, the corresponding "style macro array" would be empty.

As a prototype, I manually created the macros.

```
\def\cCenter{0,1,2}
\def\cLeft{3}
\def\cRight{}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    left column/.list={\cLeft}, %
    center column/.list={\cCenter}, %
    right column/.list={\cRight}, %
]{FILE}
```

It compiled as long as the "macro array" was not empty. If the "array" was empty, the compilation halted. Using an if-case to only include column styles which should be applied, did also not work. This left no possibility to influence the column alignment procedurally.

### Questions:

1. Did I miss a `pgfplotstable` macro which would allow me to do what I want to do?
2. Is there perhaps a way with the `expl3` syntax?
3. Or, in the worst case scenario, is it simply not possible with `pgfplotstable` to achieve my goal? If so, is there an alternative way of parsing tables from files (e.g. with `datatool`) which would provide similar functionality like `pgfplotstable` (especially `preproc cell content`, `postproc cell content` will be required for my project in the future)?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with [`catchfile`](https://ctan.org/pkg/catchfile) and [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) packages based on my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628855/106776) to another question:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

%% % used to make page size smaller and therewith facilitate page break testing
%\usepackage[
%  paperheight=7.5cm, paperwidth=13cm,
%  left=0.5cm, right=0.5cm, top=0.25cm,
%  bottom=0.25cm, includeheadfoot
%]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
  \catcode`\^^M=\active %
  \cs_gset_protected:Npn \NormalizeData #1 {%
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { \s * \r ? $ } {} #1
    \tl_greplace_all:Nnn #1 {^^M} {\\}%
    \tl_greplace_all:Nnn #1 {,} {&}%
  }%
\group_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\fancyTable}[2][]{
  \CatchFileDef{\mydata}{#2}{\catcode`\^^M=\active}
  \NormalizeData{\mydata}
  \begin{longtblr}[
    expand = \mydata,
    caption = {The Caption of the Table},
  ]{
    colspec = {#1},
    hline{1,Z} = {0.08em},
    hline{2} = {0.05em},
    row{even} = {gray9},
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    rowhead = 1,
  }
    \mydata
  \end{longtblr}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{628719.csv}
    date, time, time zone, event
    2019/01/01, 00:00, CET, server installation finished
    2019/01/01, 00:05, CET, server successfully booted
    2019/01/01, 00:06, CET, starting xyz daemon
    2019/01/01, 00:10, CET, admin login
    2019/12/31, 23:58, CET, sudo reboot
    2019/12/31, 23:59, CET, server reboot
\end{filecontents*}

%\fancyTable[r]{628719.csv}   % specify only the first column

\fancyTable[rc]{628719.csv}   % specify only the first two columns

%\fancyTable[rcc]{628719.csv} % specify only the first three columns

\fancyTable[rccl]{628719.csv} % specify all of the four columns

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It does what I need it to do, except when I compile it on my machine (Archlinux with newest texlive install), I get an additional empty row at the end. Additionally, the caption does not copy the styles I set with \usepackage{caption}. Manual editing of the caption did throw an error. Since I am not familiar with longtblr, could you please explain this in more details?

Comment: @dsacre I have tested it with the latest version 2021Q of `tabularray` package on Overleaf, which should be running a Linux system, and can not see an additional empty row. Please update your TeXLive to the lastest.

Comment: @dsacre You can use `\SetTblrStyle` and `\SetTblrTemplate` commands to customize the caption with `tabularray` package. For example, `\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}` will make the label boldface. Please read the documentation of `tabularray` package first. In case of trouble, you may ask a new question in this site.

Comment: @LJR I am using the TeXLive packages that ship with Archlinux. According to my package manager, they were updated to the newest version (2021). Since everything was working for me when using Overleaf, I will try a different OS with a different TeXLive-Install.

Comment: @LJR Now I also managed to reproduce the error of an added empty line with Overleaf. Occured only after several compilations. Will try to investigate what might be the cause.

Comment: @dsacre I have edited the answer, removing ending newline chars in the csv file. You may try it again,