# How to auto-copy the formatting from \usepackage{caption} to the caption of tabularray?

Tags: formatting, captions, tabularray

For a project I am working on, `tabularray` has been suggested in the answers to my previous questions (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628719/how-to-procedually-set-column-type-in-pgfplotstable-for-each-column-individually) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628775/how-to-achieve-reliable-tables-with-multiple-captions-with-pgfplotstable-and-lon)).

However, there will be other floats (figures, listings, etc.) with captions styled via `\usepackage{caption}`. The problem is that the caption provided by `tabularray` does not react to the settings made with `\usepackage{caption}`.

Since the design requirement is that all caption have to look the same, it is required to re-style the caption of `longtblr`.

### Starting point

`tabularray` provides with the `\DefTblrTemplate` macro a possible way to re-style the macro manually.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tabularray} % for table typesetting

% modifying the captions of tabularray
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}{\small \bfseries Table\hspace{0.25em}\thetable}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}{\small \bfseries :\enskip}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}{\small\InsertTblrText{caption}}

% setting the captions for all floats except tabularray
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelfont=bf,font=small,labelsep = colon}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {The Caption of the {\ttfamily longtblr} environment.},
  ]{
    colspec = {rccl},
    hline{Z} = {0.08em},
    hline{2} = {0.05em},
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    rowhead = 1,
  }
    date       & time  & time zone & event \\
    2019/01/01 & 00:00 & CET & server installation finished\\
    2019/01/01 & 00:05 & CET & server successfully booted\\
    2019/01/01 & 00:06 & CET & starting xyz daemon\\
\end{longtblr}
    
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption of a standard table styled with {\ttfamily captions}.}\vspace{0.25cm}
    \begin{tabular}{rccl}
        \textbf{date} & \textbf{time} & \textbf{time zone} & \textbf{event} \\
        \hline
        2019/01/01 & 00:00 & CET & server installation finished\\
        2019/01/01 & 00:05 & CET & server successfully booted\\
        2019/01/01 & 00:06 & CET & starting xyz daemon\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This produces very similar caption styling; except for the space between "Table" and the number (which is not a big deal for me and could easily be fixed). However, a user would have to do the setup twice.

### Question

1. Is there an easy way to copy the caption settings of `\usepackage{caption}` to `tabularray`?
2. Or is it easier to re-define the standard `\caption` macro manually instead of relying on the `\usepackage{caption}`?

I have tried to use an if-statement and helper macros, which of course lead to missing `\csname` or expansion errors. And honestly, the code was getting quite messy.

Comment: I have edited your question, removing unrelated text, to make the decription and the example minimal.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, `caption` package provides `\captionof` command, which can be used by `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

% setting the captions for all floats except tabularray
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelfont=bf,font=small,labelsep = colon}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_empty:n { e } { TF }
\let \IfTokenListEmpty = \tl_if_empty:eTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

% modifying the captions of tabularray
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{default}{%
  \addtocounter{table}{-1}%
  \IfTokenListEmpty{\InsertTblrText{entry}}{%
    \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
  }{%
    \captionof{table}[\InsertTblrText{entry}]{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
  }%
}
\DefTblrTemplate{middlehead,lasthead}{default}{%
  \addtocounter{table}{-1}%
  \captionof{table}[]{\InsertTblrText{caption}(Continued)}%
}
\SetTblrTemplate{caption-lot}{empty}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {The Caption of {\ttfamily longtblr} environment.},
  ]{
    colspec = {rccl},
    hline{Z} = {0.08em},
    hline{2} = {0.05em},
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    rowhead = 1,
  }
    date       & time  & time zone & event \\
    2019/01/01 & 00:00 & CET & server installation finished\\
    2019/01/01 & 00:05 & CET & server successfully booted\\
    2019/01/01 & 00:06 & CET & starting xyz daemon\\
\end{longtblr}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {The Caption of {\ttfamily longtblr} environment.},
    entry = {The Caption in LOT},
  ]{
    colspec = {rccl},
    hline{Z} = {0.08em},
    hline{2} = {0.05em},
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    rowhead = 1,
  }
    date       & time  & time zone & event \\
    2019/01/01 & 00:00 & CET & server installation finished\\
    2019/01/01 & 00:05 & CET & server successfully booted\\
    2019/01/01 & 00:06 & CET & starting xyz daemon\\
\end{longtblr}
    
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption of a standard table styled with {\ttfamily captions}.}\vspace{0.25cm}
    \begin{tabular}{rccl}
        \textbf{date} & \textbf{time} & \textbf{time zone} & \textbf{event} \\
        \hline
        2019/01/01 & 00:00 & CET & server installation finished\\
        2019/01/01 & 00:05 & CET & server successfully booted\\
        2019/01/01 & 00:06 & CET & starting xyz daemon\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to add `\InsertTblrText{entry}` in the optional argument of `\captionof` and add `\SetTblrTemplate{caption-lot}{empty}`. Otherwise there will be duplicate entries in the list of tables.

Comment: @marv Thanks. I have updated the answer. Note that I need to check whether `\InsertTblrText{entry}` is empty.

Comment: That makes sense. Maybe this could be incorperated in a `\NewTblrLibrary{caption}` ? The template system of `tabularray` is very nice, but the `caption` package is very popular and setting styles with two different syntaxes is cumbersome.

Comment: @marv Yes, it is a good idea to add a new library `caption`.

Comment: @L.J.R. and @marv A `\NewTblrLibrary{caption}` would be great!

Comment: this doesn't work well if hyperref is used, you get duplicated destinations: ` destination with the same identifier (name{table.0.2})`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I want to use this solution as a personal library (my own sty). The problem you mention does cause any weird stuff that should I be aware of? If I need to open a new question let me know.