# How to set the caption width in a longtblr from tabularray?

Tags: captions, longtable, tabularray

I have a thin longtable, but would like to have a caption with full text width. The longtable does not work in the table environment.
I tried an extra line with `\SetCell[c=5]{c}\hspace{0.9\textwidth}\\` but that moves everything weirdly and all lines become also the full width, makes sense but is not want I want.

Ideas anyone?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {Variation der Steuerungs-Simulationsversuche. Test 1-9 mit der neuer Steuerung, Test 1-14 mit Steuerung~1 und Test 15-19 mit Steuerung~2 durchgeführt. \(n_{fc}\) = Anzahl {FC} im {FC}-System, WD = Wintertag, SD = Sommertag},
        entry = {Steuerungs-Simulationsversuche},
        label = {tab:sim:steuerung_versuche},
        ]{
            colspec =ccccc,   
            rowhead = 1,     
        }
        \toprule
        Num. &  \(n_{fc}\) & Lasttag & Heizung & {PV}\\
        \midrule
        1 & 100 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        2 & 99  & WD& ein& aus \\*
        3 & 101 & WD& ein& aus \\
        4 & 200 & WD& ein& aus\\
        5 & 199 & WD& ein& aus\\
        6 & 201 & WD& ein& aus\\
        7 & 100 & SD& aus& Juli\\
        8 & 200 & SD& aus& Juli\\*
        9 & 300 & WD& aus& aus\\
        \midrule
        10& 100 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        11& 200 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        12& 300 & WD& ein& aus\\
        13& 100 & SD& aus& Juli\\*
        14& 200 & SD& aus& Juli\\
        \midrule
        15& 100 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        16& 200 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        17& 300 & WD& ein& aus\\
        18& 100 & SD& aus& Juli\\*
        19& 200 & SD& aus& Juli\\*
        \bottomrule
        
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use `caption` package and the `\captionof` command. See also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628900/how-to-auto-copy-the-formatting-from-usepackagecaption-to-the-caption-of-tabu) post. You can specify a `width` for all captions. This also has the advantage, that your `longtblr` tables will have the format as regular tables.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain,labelfont=bf,font=small, width=\linewidth}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

% modifying the captions of tabularray
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{default}{\addtocounter{table}{-1}\captionof{table}[\InsertTblrText{entry}]{\InsertTblrText{caption}}}
\DefTblrTemplate{middlehead,lasthead}{default}{\addtocounter{table}{-1}\captionof{table}[]{\InsertTblrText{caption}~(Continued)}}
\SetTblrTemplate{caption-lot}{empty}

\begin{document}
    
    \listoftables
    
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {Variation der Steuerungs-Simulationsversuche. Test 1-9 mit der neuer Steuerung, Test 1-14 mit Steuerung~1 und Test 15-19 mit Steuerung~2 durchgeführt. \(n_{fc}\) = Anzahl {FC} im {FC}-System, WD = Wintertag, SD = Sommertag},
        entry = {Steuerungs-Simulationsversuche},
        label = {tab:sim:steuerung_versuche},
        ]{
            colspec =ccccc,
            rowhead = 1,     
        }
        \toprule
        Num. &  \(n_{fc}\) & Lasttag & Heizung & {PV}\\
        \midrule
        1 & 100 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        2 & 99  & WD& ein& aus \\*
        3 & 101 & WD& ein& aus \\
        4 & 200 & WD& ein& aus\\
        5 & 199 & WD& ein& aus\\
        6 & 201 & WD& ein& aus\\
        7 & 100 & SD& aus& Juli\\
        8 & 200 & SD& aus& Juli\\*
        9 & 300 & WD& aus& aus\\
        \midrule
        10& 100 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        11& 200 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        12& 300 & WD& ein& aus\\
        13& 100 & SD& aus& Juli\\*
        14& 200 & SD& aus& Juli\\
        \midrule
        15& 100 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        16& 200 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        17& 300 & WD& ein& aus\\
        18& 100 & SD& aus& Juli\\*
        19& 200 & SD& aus& Juli\\*
        \bottomrule 
    \end{longtblr}
        
\end{document}
```

[image: longtblr full width caption]

If you want to specify the `width` locally, remove the `width=\linewidht` from the loading option and use

```
\captionsetup{width=\linewidth}
```

in a local group enclosing the `longtblr` environment.

I would also move the explanation of the variables meaning inside a `remark`, which would also make you caption a bit shorter.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this also within `tabularray` with a theme.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{wide}{%
  \makebox[\hsize][c]{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
      \UseTblrTemplate {caption-tag}{default}%
      \UseTblrTemplate {caption-sep}{default}%
      \UseTblrTemplate {caption-text}{default}%
    }
  }
}
\NewTblrTheme{widecaption}{%
    \SetTblrTemplate{caption}{wide}%
}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{longtblr}[
        theme = widecaption,
        caption = {Variation der Steuerungs-Simulationsversuche. Test 1-9 mit der neuer Steuerung, Test 1-14 mit Steuerung~1 und Test 15-19 mit Steuerung~2 durchgeführt. \(n_{fc}\) = Anzahl {FC} im {FC}-System, WD = Wintertag, SD = Sommertag},
        entry = {Steuerungs-Simulationsversuche},
        label = {tab:sim:steuerung_versuche},
        ]{
            colspec =ccccc,   
            rowhead = 1,     
        }
        \toprule
        Num. &  \(n_{fc}\) & Lasttag & Heizung & {PV}\\
        \midrule
        1 & 100 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        2 & 99  & WD& ein& aus \\*
        3 & 101 & WD& ein& aus \\
        4 & 200 & WD& ein& aus\\
        5 & 199 & WD& ein& aus\\
        6 & 201 & WD& ein& aus\\
        7 & 100 & SD& aus& Juli\\
        8 & 200 & SD& aus& Juli\\*
        9 & 300 & WD& aus& aus\\
        \midrule
        10& 100 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        11& 200 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        12& 300 & WD& ein& aus\\
        13& 100 & SD& aus& Juli\\*
        14& 200 & SD& aus& Juli\\
        \midrule
        15& 100 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        16& 200 & WD& ein& aus\\*
        17& 300 & WD& ein& aus\\
        18& 100 & SD& aus& Juli\\*
        19& 200 & SD& aus& Juli\\*
        \bottomrule
        
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]