# Using longtable and makecell, how can I get different alignments for different columns?

Tags: longtable, alignment, makecell

I have a two-page (long)table, on landscape orientation. I would like the first column to be centered-centered, but the remaining columns to be top-left (using makecell).

I would like each row to look like this:

[image: Desired Table]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\lw}
\setlength{\lw}{2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommand\tab{\hspace{10mm}}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin=1in}
\begin{landscape}
\singlespacing
\begin{longtable}{|M{1.4in-\lw}|R{2.55in-\lw}|R{2.3in-\lw}|R{2.7in-\lw}|}
Test Header & Test Header & Test Header & Test Header \\
\hline
Long First Row Name
& \makecell[tl]{Item 1 \\
    \tab Value 1 \\
    Item 2 \\
    \tab Value 2 \\
    Item 3 \\
    \tab Value 3 \\
    Item 4 with a very long name that \\ needs two lines \\
    \tab Value 4}
& \makecell[tl]{Item 5 \\
    \tab Value 5 \\
    Item 6 \\
    \tab Value 6}
& \makecell[tl]{Item 7 \\
    \tab Value 7 \\
    Item 8 \\
    \tab Value 8}
\hline
\end{longtable}
\doublespacing
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

Here is what it gets me:

[image: Coded Table]

What can I do to get my code to match the first table shown?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

- Using `tabularray` package enable relative simple table code without use of `makecell` packages.
- From example of table is not evident, why your table should be in `landscape` orientation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand\tab{\par\hspace{2em}}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin=1in}
    \begin{landscape}
\singlespacing
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption={longtable},
  label={tab:x} 
                    ]{%
        rowhead=1,
        hlines, vlines,
        colspec={X[0.7,c,m] 
                 *{3}{X[1.1,l,h]}},
        row{1} ={font=\bfseries}
                    }
Test Header 
    & Test Header 
        & Test Header       
            & Test Header           \\
Very, Very Long First Row Name
    &   Item 1
        \tab    Value 1\par 
        Item 2 
        \tab    Value 2\par 
        Item 3
        \tab    Value 2\par
        Item 4 with a very long name that needs two lines
        \tab    Value 4
        &   Item 5
            \tab    Value 5\par
            Item 6
            \tab    Value 6 
            &   Item 7
                \tab    Value 7\par 
                Item 8
                \tab    Value 8     \\                 
%
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

In table code you may replace all `\par` commands with empty lines, i.e. write the first two columns as:

```
% ...
Very, Very Long First Row Name
    &   Item 1
        \tab    Value 1
        
        Item 2 
        \tab    Value 2
        
        Item 3
        \tab    Value 2
        
        Item 4 with a very long name that needs two lines
        \tab    Value 4
        &   Item 5
% rest of table code
```

In both cases the result of compilations are the same:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this could work. Is there a way I can specify the caption formatting? I need it to match the rest of my thesis.

Comment: @Genevieve, my suggestion works for sure ... Regarding caption style: yes, it can be customized.  For example, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628900/

Comment: I was able to format the caption using the built-in \SetTblrStyle commands for tabularray. However, I cannot figure out how to remove the hanging indent for the table caption on continued pages. Any advice?

Comment: @Genevieve, hm, this deserve new question. On such more people will be able to see your problem and consequently able to help you. I Thing, that your basic question is solved (and can be accepted)

Comment: Will do. Thank you for all your help!