# How to fix the caption spacing in tblr and talltblr environments from the tabularray package?

Tags: tables, spacing, paragraphs, legend, tabularray

The spacing between the text and the table legend is different between the tblr and talltblr environments. In MWE this difference can be observed.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext a little more text\par%
%
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Caption 1}%
\label{TAB1}%
\begin{tblr}{colspec={%
X[c,m]%
X[c,m]%
X[c,m]%
}}%
\hline
\textbf{Column 1} &
\textbf{Column 1} &
\textbf{Column 1} \\%
\hline
416,09 & 176,20 & 56,00 \\
416,09 & 194,30 & 56,00 \\
416,09 & 336,10 & 56,00 \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\end{table}%
%\newpage
\blindtext a little more text\par%
%
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{talltblr}[%
caption={Caption 2},
label={TAB2},
remark{a}={text}
]{%
colspec={%
X[c,m]%
X[c,m]%
X[c,m]%
},
rowhead=1}%
\hline
\textbf{Column 1} &
\textbf{Column 1} &
\textbf{Column 1} \\%
\hline
416,09 & 176,20 & 56,00 \\
416,09 & 194,30 & 56,00 \\
416,09 & 336,10 & 56,00 \\
\hline
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not only the space above, but also the space below is different.

The caption of Table 1 is the ordinary caption. The caption of Table 2 is created by `tabularray`.

You can use `caption` package to customize the caption of Table 1:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no more needed in up-to-date distributions
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{
  position=above, aboveskip=4pt,
  belowskip=-2pt
  }
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext a little more text\par%
%
\begin{table}[h]
\centering%
\caption{Caption 1}%
\label{TAB1}%
\begin{tblr}{colspec={%
X[c,m]%
X[c,m]%
X[c,m]%
}}%
\hline
\textbf{Column 1} &
\textbf{Column 1} &
\textbf{Column 1} \\%
\hline
416,09 & 176,20 & 56,00 \\
416,09 & 194,30 & 56,00 \\
416,09 & 336,10 & 56,00 \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\end{table}%
%\newpage
\blindtext a little more text\par%
%
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{talltblr}[%
caption={Caption 2},
label={TAB2},
remark{a}={text}
]{%
colspec={%
X[c,m]%
X[c,m]%
X[c,m]%
},
rowhead=1}%
\hline
\textbf{Column 1} &
\textbf{Column 1} &
\textbf{Column 1} \\%
\hline
416,09 & 176,20 & 56,00 \\
416,09 & 194,30 & 56,00 \\
416,09 & 336,10 & 56,00 \\
\hline
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:*
If you would like to do the contrary (that is to customize the caption created by `tabularray`, so that it looks like the ordinary caption) use `presep` and `headsep` with `longtblr` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no more needed in up-to-date distributionsè-
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \blindtext a little more text\par%
    %
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \caption{Caption 1}%
        \label{TAB1}%
        \begin{tblr}{colspec={%
                    X[c,m]%
                    X[c,m]%
                    X[c,m]%
            }}%
            \hline
            \textbf{Column 1} &
            \textbf{Column 1} &
            \textbf{Column 1} \\%
            \hline
            416,09 & 176,20 & 56,00 \\
            416,09 & 194,30 & 56,00 \\
            416,09 & 336,10 & 56,00 \\
            \hline
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}%
    %\newpage
    \blindtext a little more text\par%
    %
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{longtblr}[%
            presep=10pt,%vertical space between table head and the above text
            caption={Caption 2},
            label={TAB2},
            headsep=1pt,%vertical space between table head and table body
            remark{a}={text}
            ]{%
                colspec={%
                    X[c,m]%
                    X[c,m]%
                    X[c,m]%
                },
                rowhead=1}%
            \hline
            \textbf{Column 1} &
            \textbf{Column 1} &
            \textbf{Column 1} \\%
            \hline
            416,09 & 176,20 & 56,00 \\
            416,09 & 194,30 & 56,00 \\
            416,09 & 336,10 & 56,00 \\
            \hline
        \end{longtblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do otherwise? I would like to customize the caption created by tabularray, so that it looks like the ordinary caption.

Comment: @DanielValenciaC. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to propose a little bit more advanced solution including both *caption spacing* adjustment and *caption format* customization.

To be short, **goals** are:

- identical spacing between caption, table body and adjacent paragraph text;
- identical caption format (i.e. sequence and contents of caption lines);
- transparent LoT control.

And the **challenge** is of:

- different types of tables (for example `tblr` and `talltblr`);
- usage of a few different packages affecting same document structures (for example [`tabularray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) and [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) both can add items to LoT);
- different packages have different ways of specifying caption formatting parameters.

### The MWE

To illustrate my solution, I have prepared a MWE. And here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}                  % a5 paper
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     % input encoding
\usepackage[english]{babel}                     % localization
\usepackage{caption}                            % caption control
\usepackage{tabularray}                         % tabularray package
\usepackage[unicode=true,                       % unicode encoded pdf strings
            colorlinks=true,                    % use colored links
            linkcolor=black,                    % color of links
           ]{hyperref}

\captionsetup[table]
             {labelsep=period,                  % caption separation for tables
              position=t,                       % caption position for tables
              justification=raggedright,        % caption alignment for tables
              singlelinecheck=off,              % don't center single line table captions
              aboveskip=2em}                    % above skip for table captions


\ExplSyntaxOn
% Tabularray theme using \captionof macro
\NewTblrTheme { captionof }
  {
    \DefTblrTemplate { caption } { default }
      {
        \addtocounter { table } { -1 }
        \tl_if_empty:NTF \lTblrEntryTl
          {
            \captionof { table }
              { \InsertTblrText { caption } }
          }
          {
            \captionof { table }
              [ \InsertTblrText { entry } ]
              { \InsertTblrText { caption } }
          }
        \vspace{ -\abovecaptionskip }
      }
    \SetTblrTemplate { caption-lot } { empty }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\noindent
\textcolor{red}{\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}

\textcolor{red}{Paragraph text.}

\begin{table}[!h]
 \begin{talltblr}
       [theme = captionof,
        headsep = \abovecaptionskip,
        caption = {Simple floating three part table (\texttt{captionof} theme)},
        entry = {Floating \texttt{talltblr} with \texttt{captionof} theme},
        label = {tab:table-simple-captionof},
        note{1} = {The first note text. And a long line of dummy text.},
        note{2} = {The second note text. And a long line of dummy text.}]
       {colspec = {ccc},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        hline{1,2,Z} = {1pt},
        vline{2-Y} = {1pt}}
  Head:A    & Head:B    & Head:C    \\
  A1        & B1        & C1        \\
  A2        & B2        & C2        \\
  A3        & B3        & C3        \\
 \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\textcolor{red}{Paragraph text.}

\listoftables

\end{document}
```

For the first, let the caption be ragged right (left-aligned without hyphenation) and consists of following elements:

- object type defined by localization rules (currently it is "Table" word);
- en-length space;
- object number;
- period;
- the caption text.

The layout is:

[image: A minimal example using \captionof macro]

The horizontal rule shows the full width of the text column. A paragraph before the table and paragraph after the table are used to **show spacing** between the table and adjacent paragraph. Below there is a *List of Tables* and in consists of single item, just as it should be.

The first two lines of the table's outer spec select `tblr` theme and set the spacing between the table body and its caption (generated by `talltblr` environment). The `\abovecaptionskip` length is calculated by [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package depending on float type (currently it is `table`). Spacing around float is default (see also [answer about corresponding lengths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26522)).

This piece of code defines `captionof` theme for `talltblr` environment:

```
\NewTblrTheme { captionof }
  {
    \DefTblrTemplate { caption } { default }
      {
        \addtocounter { table } { -1 }
        \tl_if_empty:NTF \lTblrEntryTl
          {
            \captionof { table }
              { \InsertTblrText { caption } }
          }
          {
            \captionof { table }
              [ \InsertTblrText { entry } ]
              { \InsertTblrText { caption } }
          }
        \vspace{ -\abovecaptionskip }
      }
    \SetTblrTemplate { caption-lot } { empty }
  }
```

In general `captionof` theme consists of two parts (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628973)):

- the first part is for definition of `caption` element of `tblr` table template;
- the second consists of line which set `caption-lot` template element to `empty`.

Setting `caption-lot` to `empty` is needed to prevent [`tabularray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) from adding of item to a List of Tables. Other lines overload `default` template of `caption` element. The text of caption is composed by [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package (when using `\captionof` macro). Running `\captionof` macro increase table counter by 1 and adds vertical spacing after caption paragraph, so it needs to decrease table counter before running `\captionof` and remove vertical spacing just after by insertion of negative spacing. If the short caption (`entry` element) in `talltblr` environment is not specified (is `empty`) `\captionof` is called without optional argument, otherwise the text value of the `entry` element is passed as optional argument. The [original solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628973) does not have spacing fixup:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_empty:n { e } { TF }
\let \IfTokenListEmpty = \tl_if_empty:eTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

% modifying the captions of tabularray
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{default}{%
  \addtocounter{table}{-1}%
  \IfTokenListEmpty{\InsertTblrText{entry}}{%
    \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
  }{%
    \captionof{table}[\InsertTblrText{entry}]{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
  }%
}
```

Hence, the tasks are distributed between the packages as follows:

- [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package composes the **text of a caption** and adds an item to the List of Tables,
- for `talltblr` environments (which is styled by `captionof` theme) [`tabularray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package provides **spacing of a caption** and pass outer specification parameters.

In addition, there is [a similar solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670265) that does not check for short captions.

### The full example

To explain my motivation of separating tasks the way above, i have prepared an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}                  % a5 paper
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     % input encoding
\usepackage[english]{babel}                     % localization
\usepackage{caption}                            % caption control
\usepackage{indentfirst}                        % first line indent
\usepackage{tabularray}                         % tabularray package
\usepackage[unicode=true,                       % unicode encoded pdf strings
            colorlinks=true,                    % use colored links
            linkcolor=black,                    % color of links
           ]{hyperref}

\captionsetup[table]
             {labelsep=period,                  % caption separation for tables
              position=t,                       % caption position for tables
              justification=raggedright,        % caption alignment for tables
              singlelinecheck=off,              % don't center single line table captions
              aboveskip=2em}                    % above skip for table captions


\UseTblrLibrary{functional}                     % to evaluate \tblrcontents


\newcommand{\normalparindent}{5ex}
\parindent=\normalparindent
\newcommand{\dummytext}{And a long line of dummy text.}
\newcommand{\nfirsttext}{The first note text. \dummytext}
\newcommand{\nsecondtext}{The second note text. \dummytext}
\newcommand{\parbot}{\par\textcolor{red}{Paragraph text.}}
\newcommand{\partop}
           {\clearpage
            \par\noindent\textcolor{red}{\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}\parbot}


\ExplSyntaxOn
% Contents of the table
\prgNewFunction \tblrcontents {}
{
  \prgReturn
    {
      Head:A    & Head:B    & Head:C    \\
      A1        & B1        & C1        \\
      A2        & B2        & C2        \\
      A3        & B3        & C3        \\
    }
}

% Period separator
\DefTblrTemplate { caption-sep } { mycapsep } { .\enskip }

% My own version of the simple caption template
\DefTblrTemplate { caption } { mysimple }
  {
    \UseTblrAlign { caption }
    \UseTblrIndent { caption }
    \UseTblrHang { caption }
    \leavevmode
    \strut
    \UseTblrTemplate { caption-tag } { default }
    \UseTblrTemplate { caption-sep } { mycapsep }
    \UseTblrTemplate { caption-text } { default }
    \strut
    \par
  }

% My own caption template
\DefTblrTemplate { caption } { mycaption }
  {
    \UseTblrAlign { caption }
    \UseTblrIndent { caption }
    \UseTblrHang { caption }
    \leavevmode
    \makebox [ \linewidth ] [ l ]
      {
        \parbox { \textwidth }
          {
            \raggedright
            \strut
            \UseTblrTemplate { caption-tag } { default }
            \UseTblrTemplate { caption-sep } { mycapsep }
            \UseTblrTemplate { caption-text } { default }
            \strut
          }
      }
  }

% Tabularray theme using mysimple template
\NewTblrTheme { mysimpletheme }
  {
    \SetTblrTemplate { caption } { mysimple }
    \SetTblrStyle { caption } { halign=l }
  }

% Tabularray theme using mycaption template
\NewTblrTheme { mycaptiontheme }
  {
    \SetTblrTemplate { caption } { mycaption }
  }

% Tabularray theme using \captionof macro
\NewTblrTheme { captionof }
  {
    \DefTblrTemplate { caption } { default }
      {
        \addtocounter { table } { -1 }
        \tl_if_empty:NTF \lTblrEntryTl
          {
            \captionof { table }
              { \InsertTblrText { caption } }
          }
          {
            \captionof { table }
              [ \InsertTblrText { entry } ]
              { \InsertTblrText { caption } }
          }
        \vspace{ -\abovecaptionskip }
      }
    \SetTblrTemplate { caption-lot } { empty }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\SetTblrInner[tblr, talltblr]
             {colspec = {ccc},
              row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
              hline{1,2,Z} = {1pt},
              vline{2-Y} = {1pt}}
\SetTblrOuter[tblr, talltblr]
             {evaluate=\tblrcontents}
\SetTblrOuter[talltblr]
             {headsep = \abovecaptionskip,
              note{1} = {\nfirsttext},
              note{2} = {\nsecondtext}}

\partop

\begin{table}[!h]
 \caption{Simple floating table}
 \label{tab:table-simple-floating}
 \begin{tblr}{}
  \tblrcontents
 \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\parbot\partop

\begin{table}[!h]
 \begin{talltblr}
       [caption = {Simple floating three part table (\texttt{default} theme)},
        entry = {Floating \texttt{talltblr} with \texttt{default} theme},
        label = {tab:table-simple-default}]{}
  \tblrcontents
 \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\parbot\partop

\begin{table}[!h]
 \begin{talltblr}
       [theme = captionof,
        caption = {Simple floating three part table (\texttt{captionof} theme)},
        entry = {Floating \texttt{talltblr} with \texttt{captionof} theme},
        label = {tab:table-simple-captionof}]{}
  \tblrcontents
 \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\parbot\partop

\begin{table}[!h]
 \begin{talltblr}
       [theme = captionof,
        caption = {Simple floating three part table (\texttt{captionof} theme)},
        label = {tab:table-simple-captionof-longcap}]{}
  \tblrcontents
 \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\parbot\partop

\begin{table}[!h]
 \begin{talltblr}
       [theme = mysimpletheme,
        caption = {Simple floating three part table (\texttt{mysimpletheme} theme)},
        entry = {Floating \texttt{talltblr} \texttt{mysimpletheme} theme},
        label = {tab:table-simple-simple}]{}
  \tblrcontents
 \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\parbot\partop

\begin{table}[!h]
 \begin{talltblr}
       [theme = mysimpletheme,
        caption = {Simple floating three part table (\texttt{mysimpletheme} theme)},
        label = {tab:table-simple-simple-longcap}]{}
  \tblrcontents
 \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\parbot\partop

\begin{table}[!h]
 \begin{talltblr}
       [theme = mycaptiontheme,
        caption = {Simple floating three part table
                   (\texttt{mycaptiontheme} theme with \texttt{simple}-like caption template,
                    \texttt{\char`\\makebox} and \texttt{\char`\\parbox})},
        entry = {Floating \texttt{talltblr} \texttt{mycaptiontheme} theme},
        label = {tab:table-simple-mycaption}]{}
  \tblrcontents
 \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\parbot

\clearpage
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

#### A very basic example

This is the layout of a simplified version of the previous table, but it is made with `tblr` environment nested in `table` float:

[image: A simple floating table using a tblr table nested in the table environment]

Looking ahead, i'd say the caption shown on the figure is *spread across the full width* of text, nor only the width of a table. This behavior is quite necessary sometime.

The part of code producing this layout is:

```
\partop

\begin{table}[!h]
 \caption{Simple floating table}
 \label{tab:table-simple-floating}
 \begin{tblr}{}
  \tblrcontents
 \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\parbot
```

`\parbot` and `\partop` macros are used to produce one paragraph before the table and one after. These paragraphs are used to **show spacing** between the floating table and adjacent paragraph. `\partop` macro also provides page breaking and draws a rule showing the full width of the text column. **Contents of the table** are provided by `\tblrcontents` macro, which is defined in `expl3`-style:

```
\prgNewFunction \tblrcontents {}
{
  \prgReturn
    {
      Head:A    & Head:B    & Head:C    \\
      A1        & B1        & C1        \\
      A2        & B2        & C2        \\
      A3        & B3        & C3        \\
    }
}
```

To get the last working, it also needs to *allow evaluation* of the macro (see `tabularray` [manual](https://mirrors.mi-ras.ru/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf#section.5.5), sec. "Outer key evaluate in action"):

```
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}                     % to evaluate \tblrcontents
```

and

```
\SetTblrOuter[tblr, talltblr]
             {evaluate=\tblrcontents}
```

The **visual style** of all tables is provided by following lines:

```
\SetTblrInner[tblr, talltblr]
             {colspec = {ccc},
              row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
              hline{1,2,Z} = {1pt},
              vline{2-Y} = {1pt}}
```

The whole picture of this table illustrates the default **vertical spacing around the float** and the **vertical spacing around the table's caption** defined by caption parameters (`aboveskip` is set to 2em intentionally):

```
\captionsetup[table]
             {labelsep=period,                  % caption separation for tables
              position=t,                       % caption position for tables
              justification=raggedright,        % caption alignment for tables
              singlelinecheck=off,              % don't center single line table captions
              aboveskip=2em}                    % above skip for table captions
```

#### A table with `default` theme

Let's take a look at the layout of the next table:

[image: A floating table using a talltblr table nested in the table environment]

and at it's code:

```
\partop

\begin{table}[!h]
 \begin{talltblr}
       [caption = {Simple floating three part table (\texttt{default} theme)},
        entry = {Floating \texttt{talltblr} with \texttt{default} theme},
        label = {tab:table-simple-default}]{}
  \tblrcontents
 \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\parbot
```

This table is typeset using `talltblr` environment. Let's say that i need to typeset a *table with notes*, so i have to use `talltblr` for a floating table. Dummy text for two **table notes** is defined as:

```
\newcommand{\dummytext}{And a long line of dummy text.}
\newcommand{\nfirsttext}{The first note text. \dummytext}
\newcommand{\nsecondtext}{The second note text. \dummytext}
```

And these notes are added to all `talltblr` tables by specifying outer parameters:

```
\SetTblrOuter[talltblr]
             {headsep = \abovecaptionskip,
              note{1} = {\nfirsttext},
              note{2} = {\nsecondtext}}
```

The macro above also specifies the **spacing between the caption paragraph and the table body**. Overall typesetting of the table is made by [`tabularray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package, no functions of [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package used. The caption paragraph appearance is default for [`tabularray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

- a text of the paragraph is justified,
- the prefix is indented with hanging,
- the separator is a colon.

It is hard to notice, but the distance between caption text baseline and top horizontal line of this table is a *little smaller* than it takes in the previous table. This caused by *no strut inserted* at the end of a text last line. This issue is not a deal with the next table, which is a variant of the very first table (see MWE).

#### A table with `captionof` theme again

This is the layout of the table mentioned in MWE, but it is typeset the other way:

[image: A floating table using a talltblr environment and captionof theme]

The piece of code is (it is less verbose, isn't it?):

```
\partop

\begin{table}[!h]
 \begin{talltblr}
       [theme = captionof,
        caption = {Simple floating three part table (\texttt{captionof} theme)},
        entry = {Floating \texttt{talltblr} with \texttt{captionof} theme},
        label = {tab:table-simple-captionof}]{}
  \tblrcontents
 \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\parbot
```

The `captionof` theme is defined just as in MWE, so layout is identical. By the way, this table is used in the example once again, but without short caption. Here is the code:

```
\partop

\begin{table}[!h]
 \begin{talltblr}
       [theme = captionof,
        caption = {Simple floating three part table (\texttt{captionof} theme)},
        label = {tab:table-simple-captionof-longcap}]{}
  \tblrcontents
 \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\parbot
```

Let's look at the List of Tables to see how table 3 and table 4 are mentioned:

[image: The List of Tables]

#### A table with `mysimpletheme` theme

Theme of the next table is inspired by this [answer about how to align the caption to the left](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=4560). The layout:

[image: A floating table using a talltblr environment and mysimpletheme theme]

and the code:

```
\partop

\begin{table}[!h]
 \begin{talltblr}
       [theme = mysimpletheme,
        caption = {Simple floating three part table (\texttt{mysimpletheme} theme)},
        entry = {Floating \texttt{talltblr} \texttt{mysimpletheme} theme},
        label = {tab:table-simple-simple}]{}
  \tblrcontents
 \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\parbot
```

Theme called `mysimpletheme` is defined by this code:

```
\NewTblrTheme { mysimpletheme }
  {
    \SetTblrTemplate { caption } { mysimple }
    \SetTblrStyle { caption } { halign=l }
  }
```

And mentioned `mysimple` caption template is defined by:

```
\DefTblrTemplate { caption } { mysimple }
  {
    \UseTblrAlign { caption }
    \UseTblrIndent { caption }
    \UseTblrHang { caption }
    \leavevmode
    \strut
    \UseTblrTemplate { caption-tag } { default }
    \UseTblrTemplate { caption-sep } { mycapsep }
    \UseTblrTemplate { caption-text } { default }
    \strut
    \par
  }
```

This template is based on `simple` template from [`tabularray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), but it use struts at both ends of a text and separator defined by my own with following line:

```
\DefTblrTemplate { caption-sep } { mycapsep } { .\enskip }
```

So, **spacing** of the caption is correct, the caption **format** is correct, and the caption **alignment** is corresponding to my requirements.

This table also have a variant without short caption.

#### A table with `mycaptiontheme` theme

The last one is a table with a theme called `mycaptiontheme`. Here comes the layout:

[image: A floating table using a talltblr environment and mycaptiontheme theme]

And the code:

```
\partop

\begin{table}[!h]
 \begin{talltblr}
       [theme = mycaptiontheme,
        caption = {Simple floating three part table
                   (\texttt{mycaptiontheme} theme with \texttt{simple}-like caption template,
                    \texttt{\char`\\makebox} and \texttt{\char`\\parbox})},
        entry = {Floating \texttt{talltblr} \texttt{mycaptiontheme} theme},
        label = {tab:table-simple-mycaption}]{}
  \tblrcontents
 \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\parbot
```

`mycaptiontheme` is defined by:

```
\NewTblrTheme { mycaptiontheme }
  {
    \SetTblrTemplate { caption } { mycaption }
  }
```

And `mycaption` template is defined by:

```
\DefTblrTemplate { caption } { mycaption }
  {
    \UseTblrAlign { caption }
    \UseTblrIndent { caption }
    \UseTblrHang { caption }
    \leavevmode
    \makebox [ \linewidth ] [ l ]
      {
        \parbox { \textwidth }
          {
            \raggedright
            \strut
            \UseTblrTemplate { caption-tag } { default }
            \UseTblrTemplate { caption-sep } { mycapsep }
            \UseTblrTemplate { caption-text } { default }
            \strut
          }
      }
  }
```

As it can be seen, the definition differs a little from one for `mysimple` caption template. The text of a caption is typeset in a `\parbox` which is nested in a box by `\makebox`. This is done to achieve caption alignment that is close to one in example with `tblr` environment, i.s. the caption paragraph should be spread across the *whole width of the text column*. Since the mentioned paragraph should be nested in the width of a table provided by `talltblr` environment (currently it is less than width of the text column), it should be placed inside a box of legal width (currently it is `\linewidth`).

This table meets the following requirements:

- **spacing** of the caption is correct,
- the caption **format** is correct,
- the caption **alignment** is correct,
- the **width of a caption paragraph** is correct.

### Conclusion

1. The **spacing** between the table body and the caption paragraph can be controlled by `aboveskip=2em` ([`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package parameter) for a table caption, whether it was provided by [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package or `talltblr` environment. It is so in case of a simple `tblr` environment and in case of themed `talltblr` environments, except for the `default` theme.
2. The **format** of a caption can be controlled in two ways:

   - label separator can be set with the `labelsep` ([`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package parameter) and it can be reused by `captionof` theme for `talltblr` environment;
   - content elements for a caption text composition can be adjusted separately — with `\captionsetup[table]` macro for [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, and with a corresponding theme (`mysimpletheme` or `mycaptiontheme` fits) for `talltblr` environment.
3. For now i havn't implemented the **paragraph justification** for a caption. The way i define it is not a generic.
4. The **paragraph width of a caption** typeset by `talltblr` environment with `mycaptiontheme` theme can be similar to one typeset by [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package. But i'm not sure about `\textwidth` usage in `mycaption` template.
5. Patches are welcome.