# Caption in longtblr doesn't follow options given to format captions

Tags: captions, siunitx, tabularray, ctable

Prior to the updates published in July 2022 I used the `ctable` package to define annotated tables. But after that date those tables containing `siunitx` columns and entries give rise to a plethora of errors, mainly referencing to `siunitx`. Browsing the internet provided me with a possible solution to the issue in the form of the `longtblr` environment provided by the `tabularray` package. So I started converting one of the problematic tables.

That conversion went well except for two errors I can't resolve. The first (major) one is the formatting of the caption of the table. I have configured that using the options of the `captions` package. These options aren't parsed onto the table caption created by `longtblr`. That caption should look the same as the one in the `ctable` example. So why not? And more importantly: how to solve / work around that?

The second (minor) question is about something odd at the last entry of the table. Somehow the `\textbf{D}` needs to stay in that cell, even though the cell is already defined as boldface in the preamble of `longtblr`. Removing that code results in a `siunitx` error and not printing of that entry.

In the given MWE both tables environments are presented. The third option using `tabularx` is commented out as that doesn't even compile. The tables are placed in a `tcolorbox` environment. The package `tcolorbox` needs to be loaded first to prevent all kind of `ams` related errors (`ams` is massively used by `chemmacros`).

If someone can point out to me why the table uisng `ctable` causes so many errors I would be grateful. Since I am going to migrate all tables to `tabularray` that answer is just a bonus to the one posed in this question.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}    %needs to be loaded first to prevent ams / math font conflicts
\tcbset{colback=gray!2.5, width=\linewidth, frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, toprule=1pt, bottomrule=1pt, sharp corners, boxsep=3pt, top=12pt, bottom=3pt,}

%----- taal/font pakketten -----
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

%----- font paketten -----
\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scale=0.95]{tgheros}

%----- chemische pakketten -----
\usepackage[modules={minimal}]{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{greek=mathdesign,formula=chemformula}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{format=\sffamily}

%----- grafische pakketten -----
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

%----- opmaak pakketten -----
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash,font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{bigdelim,bigstrut}
\usepackage{dashrule}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}

%----- layout pakketten -----
\usepackage[text={17.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{xstring}

%----- wiskunde paketten -----
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    table-alignment-mode=format,
    table-number-alignment=center,
    output-decimal-marker={,},
    reset-text-family=false, % doesn't work - math roman font is still selected
    detect-all  % now undocumented, but needed to maintain the tgheros font in siuntitx macros
    }

%----- aanvullende pakketten ----
%\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{float}


%----- font en versie selectie -----
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{40pt}

\tcbset{colback=gray!2.5, width=\linewidth, frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, toprule=1pt, bottomrule=1pt, sharp corners, boxsep=3pt, bottom=3pt,}


\begin{document}

Using the \textit{ctable}-package to create an annotated table (used to compile correctly prior to the July 2022 updates):

\begin{tcolorbox}[top=-12pt]
    \ctable[pos=H,caption={Analyse van de synthese van \textit{cafeïne} volgens Traube uit 1900}]
        {| p{2.4cm}  S[table-format=3.3] | p{2.4cm}  S[table-format=3.3] | p{2.4cm}  S[table-format=3.3] |}
        {\tnote[1]{MW staat voor molecuulmassa in \si{\g\per\mole}}
        \tnote[2]{Afvalstoffen zijn in \textcolor{red}{rood} weergegeven.}}{
        \FL
        \rowcolor{yellow!30}    \multicolumn{2}{| c}{\textbf{Reagent}}  & \multicolumn{2}{| c}{\textbf{Gebruikt in cafeïne}}    &   \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{\textbf{Niet gebruikt}} \\
        \rowcolor{yellow!10}    \textit{Formule}    & \textit{MW}   & \textit{Formule}  &   MW  &   \textit{Formule}    &   \textit{MW} \ML
        \ch{C3H8N2O}    &   88.114  &   \ch{C3H6N2O}    &   86.098  &                               &       \ML
        \ch{C3H3NO2}    &   85.064  &   \ch{C3HNO}      &   67.048  &   \textcolor{red}{\ch{H2O}}   &   18.016  \ML
        \ch{HNO2}       &   47.018  &   \ch{N}          &   14.01   &   \textcolor{red}{\ch{H2O}}   &   18.016  \ML
        2 \ch{H2}       &   4.032   &                   &           &   \textcolor{red}{\ch{H2O}}   &   18.016  \ML
        \ch{HCOOH}      &   46.026  &   \ch{C}          &   12.01   &   \textcolor{red}{\ch{H2O}}   &   18.016  \ML
        \ch{NaOH}       &   39.998  &                   &           &   \textcolor{red}{2 \ch{H2O}} &   36.032  \ML 
        \ch{CH3Cl}      &   50.484  &   \ch{CH3}        &   15.034  &   \textcolor{red}{\ch{NaCl}}  &   58,44   \ML
        \rowcolor{yellow!30}    \multicolumn{2}{| c}{\textbf{Totaal}}   &   \multicolumn{2}{| c}{\textbf{Cafeïne}}  &   \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{\textbf{Restant}} \ML
        \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \ch{C8H10N4O2} & 194.20 & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D}     
        \LL
    }
\end{tcolorbox}

%   \begin{tabularx}
%       {| p{3.0cm}  S[table-format=3.3] | p{3.0cm}  S[table-format=3.3] | p{3.0cm}  S[table-format=3.3] |}
%       \toprule
%       \rowcolor{yellow!30}    \multicolumn{2}{| c}{\textbf{Reagent}}  & \multicolumn{2}{| c}{\textbf{Gebruikt in cafeïne}}    &   \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{\textbf{Niet gebruikt}} \\
%       \rowcolor{yellow!10}    \textit{Formule}    & \textit{MW}   & \textit{Formule}  &   \textit{MW} &   \textit{Formule}    &   \textit{MW} \tabularnewline \midrule
%       \ch{C3H8N2O}    &   88.114  &   \ch{C3H6N2O}    &   86.098  &                               &       \tabularnewline \midrule
%       \ch{C3H3NO2}    &   85.064  &   \ch{C3HNO}      &   67.048  &   \textcolor{red}{\ch{H2O}}   &   18.016  \tabularnewline \midrule
%       \ch{HNO2}       &   47.018  &   \ch{N}          &   14.01   &   \textcolor{red}{\ch{H2O}}   &   18.016  \tabularnewline \midrule
%       2 \ch{H2}       &   4.032   &                   &           &   \textcolor{red}{\ch{H2O}}   &   18.016  \tabularnewline \midrule
%       \ch{HCOOH}      &   46.026  &   \ch{C}          &   12.01   &   \textcolor{red}{\ch{H2O}}   &   18.016  \tabularnewline \midrule
%       \ch{NaOH}       &   39.998  &                   &           &   \textcolor{red}{2 \ch{H2O}} &   36.032  \tabularnewline \midrule
%       \ch{CH3Cl}      &   50.484  &   \ch{CH3}        &   15.034  &   \textcolor{red}{\ch{NaCl}}  &   58,44   \tabularnewline \midrule
%       \rowcolor{yellow!30}    \multicolumn{2}{| c}{\textbf{Totaal}}   &   \multicolumn{2}{| c}{\textbf{Cafeïne}}  &   \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{\textbf{Restant}} \tabularnewline \midrule
%       \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \ch{C8H10N4O2} & 194.20 & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D}     
%       \bottomrule
%   \end{tabularx}
    
%\clearpage

Same table as above using the \textit{tabularray}-package.

\begin{tcolorbox}[top=-12pt]
\begin{longtblr}
    [   caption={Analyse van de synthese van \textit{cafeïne} volgens Traube uit 1900}, %<- doesn't use the formating options given for captions
        remark{1}={\small MW staat voor molecuulmassa in \unit{\g\per\mole}},
        remark{2}={\small Afvalstoffen zijn in \textcolor{red}{rood} weergegeven},
    ]{
    colsep=10pt,
    colspec={p{2.4cm} 
        Q[si={table-format=3.3,},c]
        p{2.4cm} 
        Q[si={table-format=3.3,},c]
        p{2.4cm} 
        Q[si={table-format=3.3,},c]
        },
    cell{1-11}{2,4,6}={wd=1.5cm}, 
    row{1,10}={bg=yellow!30,font=\bfseries},
    row{2}={bg=yellow!10, font=\itshape},
    cell{11}{1,2,5,6}={font=\bfseries,c},
    cell{3-9}{5}={fg=red},
    hline{1-12}={blue5, solid, 1pt},
    vline{1,3,5,7}={blue5, solid, 1pt},
    }
        \SetCell[c=2]{c} Reagent    & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Gebruikt in cafeïne    & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Niet gebruikt & \\
        Formule         &   MW      &       Formule     &   MW      &   Formule     &   MW  \\
        \ch{C3H8N2O}    &   88.114  &   \ch{C3H6N2O}    &   86.098  &               &       \\
        \ch{C3H3NO2}    &   85.064  &   \ch{C3HNO}      &   67.048  &   \ch{H2O}    &   18.016  \\
        \ch{HNO2}       &   47.018  &   \ch{N}          &   14.01   &   \ch{H2O}    &   18.016  \\ 
        2 \ch{H2}       &   4.032   &                   &           &   \ch{H2O}    &   18.016  \\
        \ch{HCOOH}      &   46.026  &   \ch{C}          &   12.01   &   \ch{H2O}    &   18.016  \\
        \ch{NaOH}       &   39.998  &                   &           &   2 \ch{H2O}  &   36.032  \\
        \ch{CH3Cl}      &   50.484  &   \ch{CH3}        &   15.034  &   \ch{NaCl}   &   58,44   \\
        \SetCell[c=2]{c}{Totaal}    & &     \SetCell[c=2]{c}{Cafeïne}   & & \SetCell[c=2]{c}{Restant}   &       \\
        A               &   B       &   \ch{C8H10N4O2}  &   194.20  &   C           &   \textbf{D}  % <- removing \textbf results in an error / not printing the last line
\end{longtblr}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the ctable version breaks as siunitx doesn't like that the row ends are hidden in alias commands, see https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/335

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happy New Year!

At use of the `tabularray` package try the following:

- That `talltblr` (and `longtblr`) consider caption settings defined by `caption` package, you need to define new table mode, where default `tabularray` caption  style replace with `captionof`, which consider `\captionsetup[table]{...}`  defined in document preamble-
- replace `longtblr` with `talltblr` (since table is in box and which cant be broken between pages)
- reduce options in `sisetup`to only needed ones
- optimize options/style settings in `talltablr` preamble
- cleanup table body from local style settings

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[text={17.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}    %needs to be loaded first to prevent ams / math font conflicts
\tcbset{colback=gray!2.5,
        width=\linewidth, frame hidden,
        boxrule=0pt, toprule=1pt, bottomrule=1pt,
        sharp corners, boxsep=3pt, top=12pt, bottom=3pt,}
%----- font paketten -----
\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scale=0.95]{tgheros}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[modules={minimal}]{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{greek=mathdesign,formula=chemformula}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{format=\sffamily}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker={,},
    reset-text-family=false, % doesn't work - math roman font is still selected
    detect-all  % now undocumented, but needed to maintain the tgheros font in siunitx macros
        }
\usepackage{caption}    % added   
\captionsetup[table]{skip=1ex,
                     font=small, labelfont=bf,
                     } % set up it as you wish

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}%[top=-12pt]
\NewTblrTheme{captionof}% for use caption set up in talltablr captions
{
    \DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}%
    {\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
     \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption}}}
}
\SetTblrStyle{remark}{font=\footnotesize}
\centering
\begin{talltblr}[   
  theme = captionof,
caption = {Analyse van de synthese van \textit{cafeïne} volgens Traube uit 1900.},  % now use the formatting options given for caption package
remark{1} = {MW staat voor molecuulmassa in \unit{\g\per\mole}},
remark{2} = {Afvalstoffen zijn in \textcolor{red}{rood} weergegeven},
                ]{colsep  = 10pt,
                  colspec = {*{3}{l Q[c, si={table-format=3.3}]}},
                  row{1-2}= {guard},
                  cell{3-9}{5} = {fg=red},
                  cell{Z}{1,2,5,6} = {guard, font=\bfseries, c},
                          row{1,Y} = {guard, bg=yellow!30, font=\bfseries},
                          row{2}   = {guard, bg=yellow!10, font=\itshape},
                  hlines  = {blue, 1pt},
                  vline{1,3,5,7} = {blue5, 1pt},
                 }
\SetCell[c=2]{c} Reagent    
                &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Gebruikt in cafeïne    
                                                &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Niet gebruikt 
                                                                            & \\
Formule         &   MW      &       Formule     &   MW      &   Formule     &   MW  \\
\ch{C3H8N2O}    &   88.114  &   \ch{C3H6N2O}    &   86.098  &               &       \\
\ch{C3H3NO2}    &   85.064  &   \ch{C3HNO}      &   67.048  &   \ch{H2O}    &   18.016  \\
\ch{HNO2}       &   47.018  &   \ch{N}          &   14.01   &   \ch{H2O}    &   18.016  \\
2 \ch{H2}       &   4.032   &                   &           &   \ch{H2O}    &   18.016  \\
\ch{HCOOH}      &   46.026  &   \ch{C}          &   12.01   &   \ch{H2O}    &   18.016  \\
\ch{NaOH}       &   39.998  &                   &           &   2 \ch{H2O}  &   36.032  \\
\ch{CH3Cl}      &   50.484  &   \ch{CH3}        &   15.034  &   \ch{NaCl}   &   58,44   \\
\SetCell[c=2]{c}{Totaal}    
                &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c}{Cafeïne}   
                                                &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c}{Restant}   
                                                                            &           \\
    A           &   B       & \ch{C8H10N4O2}    &   194.20  &   C           &   D       \\
     \end{talltblr}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Happy New Year too. May it be a good year. I studied your code. Thanks for giving me the answer to the caption question. So I have to define a theme for tabularray to use. I came across that reading the manual, but didn't connect that to my question :-S .

Comment: you added a few new lines in the preamble of the table. Why using 'row{1-2}={guard}' ? If it's to protect the text in those rows, row Y (10) should be guarded as well. Leaving out that option doesn't seem te affect the output anyway.

Comment: In your answer the content of the last cell is empty. There should be a bold D present. Adding that to your answer, the siunitx errors occurred again. Maybe it has something to do with the issue @Ulrike Fischer pointed out in her comment. I am going to turn that minor question into a new question.

Comment: @alchemist, (regarding above comment) oh I simple  lost it. I add them now.

Comment: @alchemist, you need to read recend package documentation. Option `guard` is added to version 2022B, and enable to vrite text in  `S` cells. Added theme is not (yet) described in documentation, but I got it in some conversation with package author. In table is not row `Y(10)` only is used option `row{˛1,Y}`. Row `Y` (Y means row before last) not need to be protected because two column cells start in columns of `l` type.

Comment: @alchemist, by mistake I add specification `row{10}` which overwrite `cell{Z}{1,2,5,6}={font=\bfseries,c}`. No is removed and inserted correct table image.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Zarko . I already adapted your code slightly to get the last cell printed too. In answer to my question about the errors occurring using D in that cell. @Joseph Wright explained the use of D in `siunitx` to denote exponential numbers (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670261/caption-in-longtblr-doesnt-follow-options-given-to-format-captions). A lone D would confuse `siunitx` as there is no number present. Putting it in curly brackets - as you did - or using `\textbf{D}` - as I did - prevents this error.

Comment: @alchemist, I just edit my answer. Added are some explanation and corrected (simplified) table preamble. Now in the last cell you can simply write "D" (since to last row is added option `guard`).

Comment: So the line `row{1-2}={guard}` has become obsolete too, since you combined the guard options with the colloring of those rows? ;-P Again thanks you for your prompt replies and very useful answers, @Zarko. Learning a lot from them, since `tabularray` was a new package to me.

Comment: @alchemist, yes, I optimize `talltblr` preamble. Now seems, that you may consider to accept answer ;-)

Comment: Already had accepted the first time you answered ;-P  Confirmed that again