# Siunitx error in last cell of a table when contents is text instead of number

Tags: tables, siunitx

In a previous question ([Caption in longtblr doesn't follow options given to format captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670261/caption-in-longtblr-doesnt-follow-options-given-to-format-captions/670265#670265)) I had a minor question regarding the formatting / output of the last cell in the `tabularray` table. The even columns in that table are defined as `siunitx` number columns, but can also contain text. This doesn't seem to be a problem, except for the last cell in the last row of the table.

The table is part of a chemistry exam question about calculating the E-factor and atom economy of the synthesis according to Traub. So the students have to determine the answer to the letters A through D before they can calculate those factors. To emphasize these determinations the letters are printed in boldface and an example of the answer is given in between B and C. In the preamble of the table that boldface printing is set using the `cell{row}{column}` formatting options.

However: when there is only the letter D in the last cell, `siunitx` compiles with a huge amount of errors, the first three being:
`Package siunitx Error: Invalid number 'D'. \end`

`Argument of \__siunitx_table_print_format_auxi:w has an extra }. \end`

`Paragraph ended before \__siunitx_table_print_format_auxi:w was complete. \end`

When the entry is presented as `\textbf{D}` the table is compiled correctly. Inserting the answer (a number) also compiles correctly

So the question remains why the letter B in the second cell of that last row does not result in syntax errors, but the letter D in the last cell does.

It may have to do with the new collecting / presenting definitions in `siunitx` version 3 as Ulrike Fischer pointed out in her comment to my earlier question about the caption: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/335 .

The MWE taken form the answer by Zarko:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[text={17.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}    %needs to be loaded prior to gfsartemsia to prevent ams / math font conflicts
\tcbset{colback=gray!2.5,
    width=\linewidth, frame hidden,
    boxrule=0pt, toprule=1pt, bottomrule=1pt,
    sharp corners, boxsep=3pt, bottom=3pt,}

%----- font paketten -----
\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scale=0.95]{tgheros}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[modules={minimal}]{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{greek=mathdesign,formula=chemformula}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{format=\sffamily}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{
    %    table-alignment-mode=format,
    %    table-number-alignment=center,
    output-decimal-marker={,},
    reset-text-family=false, % doesn't work - math roman font is still selected
    detect-all  % now undocumented, but needed to maintain the tgheros font in siuntitx macros
}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash,font=small]{caption}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \NewTblrTheme{captionof}% for use caption set up in talltablr captions
        {
            \DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}%
            {\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
                \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption}}}
        }
        \SetTblrStyle{remark}{font=\footnotesize}
        \centering
        \begin{talltblr}[   
            theme = captionof,
            caption = {Analyse van de synthese van \textit{cafeïne} volgens Traube uit 1900.},  % now uses the formatting options given for caption package
            remark{1} = {MW staat voor molecuulmassa in \unit{\g\per\mole}},
            remark{2} = {Afvalstoffen zijn in \textcolor{red}{rood} weergegeven},
            ]{
                stretch=1.2,
                colsep  = 10pt,
                colspec = {*{3}{l Q[c, si={table-format=2.3}]}},
%               row{1-2}= {guard},
                cell{Z}{1,2,5,6}={font=\bfseries,c},
                cell{3-9}{5}={fg=red},
                row{1,Y}= {bg=yellow!30, font=\bfseries},
                row{2}  = {bg=yellow!10, font=\itshape},
                hlines  = {blue, 1pt},
                vline{1,3,5,7}={blue5, solid, 1pt}, 
            }
            \SetCell[c=2]{c} Reagent    
            &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Gebruikt in cafeïne    
            &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Niet gebruikt 
            & \\
            Formule         &   MW      &       Formule     &   MW      &   Formule     &   MW  \\
            \ch{C3H8N2O}    &   88.114  &   \ch{C3H6N2O}    &   86.098  &               &       \\
            \ch{C3H3NO2}    &   85.064  &   \ch{C3HNO}      &   67.048  &   \ch{H2O}    &   18.016  \\
            \ch{HNO2}       &   47.018  &   \ch{N}          &   14.01   &   \ch{H2O}    &   18.016  \\
            2 \ch{H2}       &   4.032   &                   &           &   \ch{H2O}    &   18.016  \\
            \ch{HCOOH}      &   46.026  &   \ch{C}          &   12.01   &   \ch{H2O}    &   18.016  \\
            \ch{NaOH}       &   39.998  &                   &           &   2 \ch{H2O}  &   36.032  \\
            \ch{CH3Cl}      &   50.484  &   \ch{CH3}        &   15.034  &   \ch{NaCl}   &   58,44   \\
            \SetCell[c=2]{c}{Totaal}    
            &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c}{Cafeïne}   
            &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c}{Restant}   
            &           \\
            A           &   B       & \ch{C8H10N4O2}    &   194.20  &   C           &      D    \\ %<- inserting \textbf{D} compiles correctly
        \end{talltblr}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
    
\end{document}
```

The output PDF can be seen in [Caption in longtblr doesn't follow options given to format captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670261/caption-in-longtblr-doesnt-follow-options-given-to-format-captions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letter `D` is one of the possible markers for an exponent part in a number. So `siunitx` finds `D` and needs to have a following value, which is missing. You need to mark this entry up as explicitly text: `{D}`.

Comment: A good 2023. And thanks for the explanation. It's something you don't think about when creating a table and question. So the `\textbf{D}` essenatially declared the D as text and not as part of a number.