# Change line spacing in tabularray's talltblr and longtblr environments caption

Tags: captions, tabularray, setspace

I want to change the line spacing or baselinestretch in captions generated using `tabularray` `talltblr` and `longtblr` environment, to mimic the "stretch" option of the `caption` package.

However using \onehalfspacing doesn't work neither if I use in the `TblrTemplate` or in the `caption-text` and `caption-tag` options

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\captionsetup[table]{%
        format=plain,
        labelsep = newline,
        singlelinecheck = false,
        labelfont = bf,
        textfont = it,
        font = {small,doublespacing},
        position = above,
        }%

\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{(Continuación)}
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{Continúa en la siguiente página}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}{\bfseries\small Tabla\hspace{0.25em}\thetable}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}{.}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}{\itshape\small \InsertTblrText{caption}}

\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{
\doublespacing
 \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}%
 \UseTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}\par%
 \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}%
}

\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{%
\doublespacing
 \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}%
 \UseTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}\par%
 \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}
 \UseTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{width=5cm}
    \caption{Example of a table with caption using tabular and caption package}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
       a & b & filler text & filler text\\
    \hline
       a & b & filler text & filler text\\
    \hline
       a & b & filler text & filler text\\
    \hline
       a & b & filler text & filler text\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}[tall, caption={Example of a table with caption using tabularray package}]{colspec={cccc},hlines,vlines}
       a & b & filler text & filler text\\
       a & b & filler text & filler text\\
       a & b & filler text & filler text\\
       a & b & filler text & filler text\\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Please show us your result in your question ...

Comment: @Mensch done. I want to reproduce caption results with tabularray.

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628900/how-to-auto-copy-the-formatting-from-usepackagecaption-to-the-caption-of-tabu/628973#628973 can help you.